# How to mix different types of views in spring configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

greetings all
i am using jsp as a view technology in my web app

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

and i want to use velocity too as a view technology in sending emails 
and i want to configure this in the xml file, but i don't know how ?

any ideas how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Velocity to construct emails, then this is not a "view", as far as Spring MVC is concerned. Views and ViewResolvers are used to render output to the browser.

Spring MVC does provide support for using Velocity as a view layer, but this isn't relevant to what you're trying to do.

However, Spring also provides some support classes to make the clunky Velocity API a bit less awkward to use (see [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/velocity/package-summary.html)). These have no relation to the Spring MVC view layer, though.  Just use them directly from your code, building the emails and sending them.

Comment: i just have a problem with using some spring methods in the vm like:<span>#springMessageText("hi.message", "Hello Default!")</span>
the app doesn't recognize the method, do you know how to solve this issue ?